# Tech Queries for chart components

Tags: jquery, .net, teechart

1. What are the browsers and versions that are fully supported by TeeChart for .NET V2013 charting components?
2. Are the charts generated on the server [web-server] or the client [browser] side?
3. What are the formats in which TeeChart for .NETV2013 chart component accepts data for plotting?
4. We will be using the chart component in our reports [that will have multiple charts]. We need to allow export of the full report along with all the charts, in various formats like DOC, PDF, PPT, etc. Our export logic is on the server side; hence, we need some mechanism in the chart component that will allow charts to be converted into images at the server-side.
5. Can a chart be saved by itself on the client-side?
6. What are the customizable attributes of the charts? Can a custom CSS be applied to the charts?
7. Can attributes like the size, caption, etc. of the chart be changed without a call to the server?
8. Are there any resources that we can refer to improve the performance of the charting component? Alternatively, is there a set method by which we can gauge the performance for ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

**1. What are the browsers and versions that are fully supported by TeeChart for .NET v2013 charting components?**
TeeChart Asp.Net offers you options because the Charts are supported by  all the browsers that support ASP.NET and/or Silverlight.

**2. Are the charts generated on the server [web-server] or the client [browser] side?**
The TeeChart for .NET WebChart adds any new data as a complete Chart change before rendering. If a complete chart refresh is unsatisfactory then more suitable would be a live client-side Chart. Steema currently offers these options for that:
- TeeChart for .NET Silverlight. Offers richer clientside support. Supported by Silverlight compatible browsers.

**3. What are the formats in which TeeChart for .NET v2013 chart component accepts data for plotting?**
TeeChartFor.Net v2013 allow you import data by Templates, Xml and Text files. I recommend you taking a look in Tutorial12 - Exporting and Importing Charts, examples of Demo project, All Features\ Welcome!\Importing, Tutorial8 - ADO.NET Database Access and All Features\Welcome !\Datasets
On the other hand, you have two components to allow you import the data file in correct way, XmlSource and TextSource. This are apply to ASP.Net and Silverlight applications.

**4. We will be using the chart component in our reports [that will have multiple charts]. We need to allow export of the full report along with all the charts, in various formats like DOC, PDF, PPT, etc. Our export logic is on the server side; hence, we need some mechanism in the chart component that will allow charts to be converted into images at the server-side.**
If you taking a look in the Tutorial12 - Exporting and Importing Charts you find some mechanism to export the chart to image using Silverlight. In the case, of Asp.Net I think you should achieve save the image apply some specific mechanism of Asp.net applications.

**5. Can a chart be saved by itself on the client-side?**
The WebChart is an image; therefore you can save the image directly of the browser, in the client-side or applying the export methods.   If you work with Silverlight, you can apply the export methods of TeeChartFor.Ne to save the image directly.

**6. What are the customizable attributes of the charts? Can a custom CSS be applied to the charts?**
You can customize all attributes of charts, in WebChart or in Silverlight, but isn’t possible apply CSS to charts.

**7. Can attributes like the size, caption, etc. of the chart be changed without a call to the server?**
If you work with Silverlight, yes. In WebChart is called the server always you change an attribute of Chart.

**8. Are there any resources that we can refer to improve the performance of the charting component? Alternatively, is there a set method by which we can gauge the performance for ourselves?**

I recommend you taking a look in this link http://www.teechart.net/reference/index.php concretely in real-time charting, that explain how you can improve the performance of the charting.

I hope will helps. 
Thanks,